# Kubernetes Ingress: Having Load Balancing + Session Stickiness by Header/Cookie Value provided in the Request

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, openshift

Following scenario in my cluster:

I have a Spring Boot RestAPI with 1 Pod running, on which we receive requests. Each of these requests go through a standart ingress, which routes to a PowerShell HTTP Listener Service, which has 10 Pods running simultaneously.

What I want to achieve is, that based on a provided header-value/cookie called "TenantId", the Ingress should create a session stickyness, but should also LoadBalance, so that each different "TenantId" lands on a seperate PowerShell Pod. Only if there is a "TenantId" already allocated on every available Pod, then it should allocate another (random) one and start from there.

Background is, that I want each PowerShell Pod to only have as minimum Tenants as possible, while also maintaining Session Affinity. I tried using cookies, but that one would of course just respond with a hashed cookie, which I would have to use in my Spring Boot Application's following requests. The issue with this is, that it doesn't LoadBalance and makes 2 different TenantIds land on the same Pod, while we have 9 other Pods just idling around. As the session is sticky from that request onwards, it will affect me negatively.

Can I somehow configure the Ingress to look for a provided Header Value and create a session stickiness/affinity based on that Value, but also LoadBalance DIFFERENT TenantIds with a "random" or "roundrobin" logic? Or is it a better approach to think of a custom router pod? If yes, what should I make use, to also make it effective in sizing?